# Where can I find a dictionary file of common words?

Tags: natural-language

It's easy to generate a [strong password](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) quickly using the system dictionary:

```
$ for i in {1..4}; do shuf --head-count=1 /usr/share/dict/words; done
Amelanchier
whitecup
ankhs
antispasmodics
```

However, this isn't exactly the easiest list of words to remember. Is there a package or file available for getting either the **N most used words** (for example Simplified English) or a list of words either **ordered by popularity** or with a **popularity index** so I can choose how many to use?

Comment: by the way why to use for loop instead using just `shuf --head-count=4 /usr/share/dict/words`?

Comment: @Pandya Because then you're reducing the number of words every time you run. The more words the less this matters, but it *does* make a difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for data that isn't related to Unix in any way. It *might* be on-topic on [opendata.se], but check their [site description](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I use the [Beale word list](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/beale.wordlist.asc) with plurals removed, and keeping only words of 3–5 letters. This gives me a little over 2¹² words which I find easily memorable. #slugtriesgoalokra

Comment: @Gilles I did ask about "Applications packaged in \*nix distributions", as per the FAQ...

Comment: @l0b0 Applications, not data.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your language, search for existing national corpora - many provide such lists, often without any licensing restrictions.

For a frequency list of English words, try [this short one from the British National Corpus](https://www.kilgarriff.co.uk/bnc-readme.html) or [longer ones from the Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.wordfrequency.info/).

Answer (score 1):

The [GNU troff/groff](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/groff.html) package has a file `eign` in it that has 133 very common english words.  On my Arch linux laptop it is: `/usr/share/groff/1.22.3/eign`

Comment: I suspect that collection is a bit too small to make for sufficient entropy while being memorable.

Comment: @l0b0 - Good point. I misread your question when I answered it. My own biases led me to believe that you were looking for a list of "stop words", words to avoid as "too common".